# Help in displaying an Image Gallery in Yii

Tags: php, css, yii

I have been working on developing an image gallery website in yii framework. I like to display a gallery of images in a page as a gird with pagination feature. I wonder if there exists any Yii builtin features like CGridView can be used for this purpose. If not what will be my best option to choose. I have to do the pagination in the gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have 3 choices: (1) Customize CGridView by extending the render functions to make it do what you want, which is pretty easy to do. (2) Find a Yii extension and see if it's close enough to what you want ( http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/ ), or (3) use a JavaScript-based image gallery and have Yii output the data.

Comment: Can you please provide me some links or examples of configuring the CGridView as you said.

Comment: see: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10414-cgridview-totals-row-under-header/ you also might want to look into CListView (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView) instead, which allows you to reference your own templates in which case you might not need to extend any classes.